# How to export tag counts to excel?

Tags: tags, count, csv

I'm not a programmer, so writing PHP code, etc. would be tough for me ... but I'm looking for a simple way to analyze which tags are used most often to tag posts in my blog. An export of tag and use count to Excel would eb brilliant.

Comment: Well, I am rebuked. I'll pack up my tent and slink away ... But perhaps I'll try to learn a little and return ... Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this stack is more focused on development, asking for ready–made solutions like plugins isn't considered in scope.

From perspective of native functionality and power user perspective you can sort tags by count in WP admin interface. You can also tweak how many tags are displayed via Screen Options (top right of page). It's possible to simply copy/paste from there to Excel too, but will likely take some cleanup.